# Different theme folders

Tags: themes, directory

If a theme is installed in either /.themes or /usr/share/themes then it is detected by unity tweak tool and can be applied.

What is the difference between these two folders?

Answer (score 1):

`/usr/share/themes` is for the system (all users)

`~/.themes` is for the current user ;)

Comment: `~/.local/share/themes` as well - also `~/.local/share/icons` for icon themes for a user, and `/usr/share/icons` for icon themes for the entire system.